# Uncertainty in laser beam width

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, error-analysis, experimental-technique

I have voltage vs position data for the cross-sectional profile of a laser beam, acquired from a photodiode, and I'm trying to find the beam's width and the uncertainty in the width. I was planning to use the half the distance between the two positions where the voltage was $e^{-2}$ times the maximum voltage, but then I'm not sure what the uncertainty would be. I was thinking I might try to find the uncertainty in the maximum voltage and propagate that, but then I wasn't sure what the uncertainty in the maximum voltage would be. How can I find the uncertainty in the beam width?

Some of the beam profiles have a nice, Gaussian shape, but some of them do not, so I'm not sure if using a Gaussian fit would work.

Comment: Please include your assumptions. It seams as if you assume a Gaussian beam. If you fit the profile, what is the standard deviation of your fit parameter describing the width $\sigma$? Why is this not a useful uncertainty?